# Wordpress enqueue CSS in child theme with version

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, themes, stylesheet

I am trying, essentially, to add the `?ver=1.0` tag to the end of my stylesheet, which I have included in my child theme's function file (enqueued). I have [read the documentation in the codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/) but it does not seem to be applying in the source code, and it is not updating/cache breaking as intended when I apply updates.

The stylesheet itself **is** being included, however, the version is not applying, so I'm somewhat at a loose end here.

This is my current code:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'kl_child_scripts',11 );
function kl_child_scripts() { 
    wp_deregister_style( 'kallyas-styles' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'kallyas-styles', get_template_directory_uri().'/style.css', '' , ZN_FW_VERSION );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'kallyas-child', get_stylesheet_uri(), array('kallyas-styles') , filemtime(get_stylesheet_directory() . '/style.css'));
```

N.B. It is the last line to which I am trying to apply the version. (kallyas-child). The previous line (kallyas-styles) does appear to have some form of version `ZN_FW_VERSION`, but that does not produce the desired effect.

`filemtime(get_stylesheet_directory() . '/style.css')` is intended to break cache and update the version number each time the file is saved. Edit: I do, now, believe that this code does in fact work, but the theme (as it is a pre-build) is preventing it from applying properly. I will update if and when I figure this out, hoping to get to talk to the theme developers.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that your are using `filemtime` which return an **int** and you should have a **string**. As you can read in the [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/) :

> $ver
>
> (string|bool|null) (Optional) String specifying stylesheet
>   version number, if it has one, which is added to the URL as a query
>   string for cache busting purposes. If version is set to false, a
>   version number is automatically added equal to current installed
>   WordPress version. If set to null, no version is added. Default value:
>   false

so you may try this :

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'kl_child_scripts',11 );
function kl_child_scripts() { 
    wp_deregister_style( 'kallyas-styles' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'kallyas-styles', get_template_directory_uri().'/style.css', '' , ZN_FW_VERSION );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'kallyas-child', get_stylesheet_uri(), array('kallyas-styles') , strval(filemtime(get_stylesheet_directory() . '/style.css')));
```

I added the [strval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strval.php) that will convert the int to string

Comment: This does seem to return correctly, i.e. if I `echo strval(filemtime(get_stylesheet_directory() . '/style.css'));` it returns `1510140577` (and updates with new saves as intended). It does not, however, apply when calling the style.css file in the source code... not sure what's going on there!

Comment: @math let's first try putting something static .. put for exmaple the value "14" in the version and see if it wokrs

Comment: Ah... good call. This is also doing nothing. `wp_enqueue_style( 'kallyas-child', get_stylesheet_uri(), array('kallyas-styles') , '4.0.0');` ...must be a problem with the theme setup, or the child theme?

Comment: @Matt and do you see version on other CSS flies ? as maybe this function is desactivated

Comment: it appears to be, yes. I am able to dequeue the file from that same function... : /

Comment: @Matt am not talking about the main function but about `wp_enqueue_style( 'kallyas-child', get_stylesheet_uri(), array('kallyas-styles') , '4.0.0');` The style is added to your page, are you able to see it ?

Comment: Ah, yes, I am able to see the stylesheet being added, there is just no version.

Comment: @Matt and is there at least another CSS file in the site that have version ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158521/discussion-between-temani-afif-and-matt).

Answer (score -1):

Use below code

```
        define('ZN_FW_VERSION','1.0');
        add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'kl_child_scripts',11 );
        function kl_child_scripts() { 
            wp_deregister_style( 'kallyas-styles' );
            wp_dequeue_style( 'kallyas-styles' );
            wp_enqueue_style( 'kallyas-styles', get_template_directory_uri().'/style.css', array() , ZN_FW_VERSION );
            wp_enqueue_style( 'kallyas-child', get_stylesheet_uri(), array('kallyas-styles') , ZN_FW_VERSION);
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

in functions.php I added

```
 wp_enqueue_style( 'kallyas-child',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
        array( 'kallyas-styles' ),
        filemtime(__DIR__.'/style.css')
    );
```

tested it at tmp.demos.rent-a-ninja.org

worked with divi theme

Comment: I had seen this way mentioned before but I would then have to manually update the version number each time I edited the CSS file, right? I am aiming for it to be done programmatically if possible.

Comment: since your approach does not work, I'm asking if your filemtime returns the propper value?

you might also try an md5 of the file?!

Comment: It seems to return correctly, i.e. if I `echo filemtime(get_stylesheet_directory() . '/style.css')` it can return `1510140577`. It does not, however, apply to the style.css tag in the source code.

Comment: why do you deregister the original parent theme?

Comment: you need to add the name of the person using @Matt if you want him to get notified about your message unless he may not see it

Comment: I just had to run out, sorry! As this is built off of the back of a pre-built theme, the deregister is actually part of the child-theme package provided by the original author. I am not personally sure why they deregister the original parent theme either!